# Как правильно соорудить выборку из БД по заданному диапазону (цены товаров)?

Tags: input, php, база-данных

Имеется следующая форма:

```
<span class="form_tovar">Цена:</span>
            <input type="text" name="price_ot" placeholder="от"/>
<span class="form_tovar">-</span>
            <input type="text" name="price_do" placeholder="до"/>
```

Задача в том, чтобы вывод из БД соответствовал критериям полей **ОТ** и **ДО**. Что для этого писать в обработчике?

Спасибо!

Comment: `SELECT a, b, c, d WHERE price >= :lower_limit AND price <= :upper_limit`

Comment: так. значит, остается вместо lower_limit и upper_limit вставить необходимые значения?

Comment: @Azat Khanov, да (плюс пол еще правильные выбрать)

Comment: Имеется еще предложение 

    WERE d BETWEEN a AND b

Comment: @Fike, не понял что имеется ввиду.
@Builder, Спасибо за варианты. Очень ценная штука!

Comment: @Azat Khanov, я тогда с ног валился уже, хотел на всякий написать, что `a, b, c, d` надо заменить на настоящие названия полей.